# How to write an add-in to extend individual tests within NUnit testcases in ParameterizedMethodSuite

Tags: nunit, add-in

I am writing an addin that would extend `NUnitTestMethod` and override its `RecordException()` method to provide more information about a test, based on several custom attributes, which a test can be tagged with.

I have, so far, managed to successfully create an addin to extend individual tests, marked by `[Test]` attribute through using `ITestDecorator` extensions. The problem occurs, when I try to do much of the same for test cases, marked by parametrised `[TestCase()]` attributes. In this case NUnit creates a so-called `ParametrizedMethodSuite`, and I cannot seem to find a way to inject my class, which inherits from NUnitTestMethod into such suite.

I've posted a question of NUnit mailing list some time ago, without getting any answer. Maybe there are some NUnit gurus here, who encountered the same problem can help me out?

For code examples from my project, please, see the post at NUnit mailing list:
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/nunit-discuss/dZW0Nc8N2LM/discussion

**EDIT:**
After studying NUnit source code in depth, I have finally figured out a way of achieving what I want, albeit in a different way.
As far as I could see, it is impossible to populate `ParameterizedMethodSuite` with your own test methods, which inherit from `NUnitTestMethod` as I cannot access private argument constructs in my derived class and thus cannot set them.
I ended up extending `ParameterizedMethodSuite` and overriding `Run()` method, with subsequent modification of `TestResult` returned from `base.Run()`
For consistency, the class, extending `NUnitTestMethod` now also overrides `Run()` method.

In the process, I also discovered an interesting anomaly: `TestResult.StackTrace` has a setter, while `TestResult.Message` does not. As I actually needed to modify the message, I was forced to go through the `SetResult()` method and update everything.

```
[NUnitAddin(Name = "Custom Tag Attribute Decorator", Description = "Outputs additional information for tests tagged with custom attributes.")]
public class TagDecorator : ITestDecorator, IAddin
{
    public Test Decorate(Test test, MemberInfo member)

    {
        List<Attribute> tags = Reflect.GetAttributes(member, false).OfType<ITestTag>().Cast<Attribute>().ToList();
        if (tags.Count == 0)
        {
            return test;
        }

        if (test is NUnitTestMethod)
        {
            return new TestMethodExtension((test as NUnitTestMethod).Method, tags);
        }

        if (test is ParameterizedMethodSuite)
        {

            ParameterizedMethodSuite suite = test as ParameterizedMethodSuite;
            ParameterizedMethodSuiteExtension outputSuite = new ParameterizedMethodSuiteExtension(member as MethodInfo, tags);
            NUnitFramework.ApplyCommonAttributes(member, outputSuite);
            outputSuite.RunState = suite.RunState;
            outputSuite.IgnoreReason = suite.IgnoreReason;


            foreach (NUnitTestMethod testMethod in suite.Tests)
            {
                outputSuite.Add(testMethod);
            }

            return outputSuite;
        }

        return test;
    }

    public bool Install(IExtensionHost host)
    {
        IExtensionPoint testDecorators = host.GetExtensionPoint("TestDecorators");
        if (testDecorators == null)
            return false;

        testDecorators.Install(this);
        return true;
    }
}


public static class TagExtensionHandler
{
    public static void ModifyTestResult(TestResult testResult, List<Attribute> tags)
    {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        message.AppendLine("Related to:");
        foreach (ITestTag taggedAttrib in tags.OfType<ITestTag>().Select(attrib => attrib))
        {
            message.Append("     ");
            message.AppendLine(taggedAttrib.GetInfo());
            message.AppendLine();
        }

        message.AppendLine();
        message.Append(testResult.Message);

        testResult.SetResult(testResult.ResultState, message.ToString(), testResult.StackTrace, testResult.FailureSite);
    }
}

public class ParameterizedMethodSuiteExtension : ParameterizedMethodSuite
{
    private readonly List<Attribute> _tags;
    public ParameterizedMethodSuiteExtension(MethodInfo method, List<Attribute> tags)
        : base(method)
    {
        _tags = tags;
    }

    public override TestResult Run(EventListener listener, ITestFilter filter)
    {
        TestResult result = base.Run(listener, filter);
        foreach (TestResult subResult in result.Results)
        {
            TagExtensionHandler.ModifyTestResult(subResult, _tags);
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class TestMethodExtension : NUnitTestMethod
{
    private readonly List<Attribute> _tags;
    public TestMethodExtension(MethodInfo methodInfo, List<Attribute> tags)
        : base(methodInfo)
    {
        _tags = tags;
    }

    public override TestResult Run(EventListener listener, ITestFilter filter)
    {
        TestResult result = base.Run(listener, filter);
        TagExtensionHandler.ModifyTestResult(result, _tags);
        return result;
    }
}
```